# Jetty with HTTP/2 enabled has CLOSE_WAIT Sockets issue

Tags: java, sockets, jetty, dropwizard, http2

We are using Jetty 9.4.40 with dropwizard. We are trying to enable HTTP/2, when we enable the HTTP/2 support, the application works without any issues for 5 to 6 hours, then we see a lot of CLOSE_WAIT connections and CPU usage goes up.

Jetty is behind the ELB. When we analyzed the thread dump, the thread which was consuming a high CPU has the following stack trace.

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.HeadersBodyParser.parse(HeadersBodyParser.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:198)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.ServerParser.parse(ServerParser.java:115)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$HTTP2Producer.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:360)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.onFillable(HTTP2Connection.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$FillableCallback.succeeded(HTTP2Connection.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:395)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokeNonBlocking(Invocable.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.invokeTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please file this as an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: try YourKit Profile to find the bottleneck or try a different version of Jetty parser